# How do I evaluate this sum: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(2n+i)^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

> $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(2n+i)^2}}=?$

How do I evaluate this?
I am a beginner, so please be gentle with your professional answers...

By the way, I am asking this because I am trying to darboux-integrate something and got this times $n$ as lower darboux sum. So I basically need the limit of this as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: $$0\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2n+i)^2}<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{1}{4n}$$ hence the limit is zero. You do not need any explicit formula involving $H_m^{(2)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the substitution $j = 2n+i$:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(2n+i)^2}} = \sum_{j=2n+1}^{3n} \frac{1}{j^2} = \sum_{j=1}^{3n} \frac{1}{j^2} - \sum_{j=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{j^2}. $$

If you want to evaluate for specific $n$,
$$\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j^2} = \left.\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\ln(\Gamma(x))\right)\right|_{x=N+1}$$
where $\Gamma(x)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function); these are the [generalized Harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalization) in power $2$.

The limit is easier, since $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}$ is a convergent series. Indeed,

$$0 \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=2n+1}^{3n} \frac{1}{j^2} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=2n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2} = 0.$$